# A challenge for sed convert code from Mathematica to Matlab

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have the following output from Mathematica to C code:

```
$ cat file.txt
Complex(1.3, 2.7)*Power(kappa, 2.0) + Complex(0.3, 2.0)*Power(kappa,5.0)*log(alpha)
```

The file is extremely long (many tens of thousands of lines). I would like to replace every Complex(a, b) with (a + i*b) and every Power(a, b) to a^b. So the above sample would look like:

```
$ cat desired_file.txt
(1.3 + i*2.7)*kappa^2.0 + (0.3 + i*2.0)*kappa^5.0*log(alpha)
```

How can I use sed to achieve this result? It is not straight forward at all by reading regular expressions and examples out there.

How can I do this using `sed`?

Comment: Would the easiest solution not just be to create your own `Complex` and `Power` functions in Matlab?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
sed 's/Complex(\([^,]*\), *\([^)]*\))/(\1 + i*\2)/g; 
     s/Power(\([^,]*\), *\([^)]*\))/\1^\2/g' file
```

**This will not work for nested statements** like `Power(Power(a, b), c)`.

#### Explanation

- To susbstitute patterns in `sed`, you use the substitution operator (`s/pattern/replacement/`). The `g` at the end means *global*, it causes the substitution to be applied to all matches.
- Patterns can be [captured](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) and reused later by placing them inside escaped parentheses: `\(` and `\)`. The first such pattern is `\1`, the second `\2` etc.
- To replace `Complex(a, b)` , I use `Complex(\([^,]*\), *\([^)]*\))`. This means match `Complex(`, then the longest string of consecutive non-`,` characters (`[^,]*`) is captured as \1, then a single comma and zero or more spaces, then the longest string of non-`)` characters until the closing parenthesis is found. The whole thing is replaced with `(\1 + i*\2)`.
- The regular expression that matches the `Power()` is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`'s string replace function:

```
sed -i 's/"complex(a, b)"/(a + i*b)/g'
```

The same for the other pattern, just replace `complex(a,b)` with the expression you want to replace and `(a + i*b)` with the string you want instead of that expression.

Comment: I think the OP is _asking_ for the expression to replace.

Comment: @terdon sorry, I misunderstood something.